# Firebase Storage Rules look right but still get "User does not have permission to access"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm experiencing firebase security rules errors and i can't figure out what's the problem.
The two conditions to `write` are that the user should be logged in and that the user requesting should have the same UserId of the folder/author

Here are my security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /images/{userId}/{imageId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    match /videos/{userId}/{videoId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    match /profileImage/{userId}/{profileImage} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

All these rules cause an error when i'm trying to upload a profile image, an image or a video.
The error that i get is:

> Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'images/LsF54H8lrFG5eKQPiEd8IUBx78c9/14211068-1225-4321-a5c0-0b55d0801d33-IMG-20200911-WA0032.jpg'. (storage/unauthorized)

The code to upload:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage"
import { storage, auth } from "../firebase";

export default function Test() {
  const user = auth.currentUser;

  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");

  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    setImage(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const imageRef = ref(
      storage,
      "profileImage/" + user?.uid + "/profilePhoto"
    );
    uploadBytes(imageRef, image)
      .then(() => {
        getDownloadURL(imageRef)
          .then((url) => {
            setUrl(url);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message, "download URL catch");
            toast.error(error.message);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message, "upload bytes URL");
        toast.error(error.message);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <h3>Profile Picture</h3>
        <img
          src={url}
          alt="Profile"
        />
        <input
          type="file"
          onChange={handleImageChange}
          id="profileImageURL"
          accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
          data-testid="upload-prompt"
        />
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
          disable={!user}
        >
          Upload Image
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how your `user` is initialized, but it seems like it does not match the UID of the currently signed in user. To troubleshoot, consider checking `if (getAuth().currentUser.uid === user)` before making the call to the Storage SDK.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, i'm not sure how to do this test because user would not be defined but i can get my user from 2 place. getAuth(), as you suggested and params which is defined in the route. I compared these 2, ```useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Auth uid: ", getAuth().currentUser.uid);
    console.log("Params uid: ", user);

    if (getAuth().currentUser.uid === user) {
      console.log("hello");
    }
  });```. From the console: ```Auth uid:  oEZkNkmobWqbdAC45OKX4cSL6nf9
Images.jsx:20 Params uid:  oEZkNkmobWqbdAC45OKX4cSL6nf9
Images.jsx:23 hello``` . I hope that this is legible.

Comment: This is where the params comes from: ```const params = useParams();
  const { user } = params;```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [full-but-minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I have just edited the question to include a repro.

Comment: Thanks. I stil think the `user` may be incorrect. One thing to change: since you only allow the user to submit when they are signed in (based on `disable={!user}`) you really shouldn't be using a `?` here: `"profileImage/" + user?.uid + "/profilePhoto"`. So another way to check for a user would be to use `"profileImage/" + user!.uid + "/profilePhoto"` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253320/discussion-between-coolkid-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Comment: So when you say user is incorrect, you mean the user is not logged in or one user is trying to update another user? Ive used ```useParams``` and ```auth.currentUser.uid```, both have the same uid and neither are able to upload images. I'm obviously missing something about security rules.
I have made the changes according to your suggestions on user?.uid vs user!.uid, no difference in outcome, thanks though.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log("uid=" + user?.uid)` at the beginning of `uploadBytes`? Also the code your provide is not the one causing the exception as the code uses the path `"profileImage/" + user?.uid + "/profilePhoto"` and the exception shows `"images/..."` - can you either update the code or the exception it throws?

Comment: I've discovered my issue. I have a firebase storage connected to a demo bucket online and the rest of my app is on the emulator. The storage account couldn't find the users and for some reason i thought it could. I apologise for the inconvenience.